# How to animate zoomScale on a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, cabasicanimation, nsvalue

I need to set zoomScale back to 1 on a UIScrollView, but I need it to be animated. I thought I could use CABasicAnimation for this, but NSValue doesn't seem to have a "valueForFloat" or "valueForNSNumber", so I'm not sure what to use for animation.fromValue and animation.toValue for the CABasicAnimation. Is there a better way to go about this?

EDIT: What do I need to add for this to work?

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"zoomScale"];
        animation.duration = 2.3;
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];        
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:myScrollview.zoomScale];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

        [myScrollview.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"zoomScale"];
```

Comment: Try to add the animation on the view that is animated not on the scrollView, because I think that the scroll's layer is not changed but the zoomed view's layer is changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don’t need to resort to `CAAnimation` for this simple thing, just use `-[UIScrollView setZoomScale:animated:]` passing `YES` as the second parameter.

Anyway, if you wanted to do modify some aspect of the animation you may resort using “UIView animations” instead, since `zoomScale` is not directly a property animatable by `CAAnimation`.

Have you tried something like the following?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{ [myScrollView setZoomScale:1.0f animated:NO]; }
                 completion:nil];
```

Comment: I want to set my own animation time though. I don't want the default animation time of setZoomScale:animated:

Comment: The you should use `NSNumber` instances as values for `fromValue` and `toValue`.